# StringBuilder, disappearing quotation marks

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I need to make a string for SQLite select functionin the format of :

> ...AND value_data IN ('FOX','BARTLETT')

where 'FOX' and 'BARTLETT' are placeholders for 1+ variable names, all surrounded by single quote and comma separated. 
Here is my code:

```
StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
build.append(") AND value_data IN (");
build.append("'" + values[0] + "'");         //guaranteed first value
for(int l = 1; l < (values.length); l++){
    build.append(",'" + values[l] + "'");   //any number of values afte
}
build.append(")");
```

But when i print out the build.toString(), I get this:

> ...AND value_data IN ('FOX,BARTLETT')

The interior single quotes that should be before and after the comma vanish. 
I've looked all over the internet (this site and others) for the answer but can't find it. Why are these quotes dissapearing and how can I make the the String build like shown at the top?

Comment: Your code is correct. Are you sure that `values` actually contains two elements, and not just one string equal to "FOX,BARTLETT"?

Comment: 1. Then `values[0]` doesn't contain what you think; your quotes aren't disappearing and your posted code is fine, but your value array was populated incorrectly. 2. Generally you do not want to build SQL queries this way. While it might be fine for your small one-off program, at minimum escape your strings before building the query. Much better, though, use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-using-prepared-callable-statement).

Comment: Either what the people above mentioned, or you're running an old version of your code which doesn't have those quotes... (like in the old days of using Eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct.

I suggest only to use StringBuilder append() instead of string concatenation for performance reasons.

```
StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
build.append(") AND value_data IN (");
build.append("'").append(values[0]).append("'"); //guaranteed first value
for (int l = 1; l < values.length; l++) {
    build.append(",'").append(values[l]).append("'"); //any number of values after
}
build.append(')');
```